# Reply Mail Management - counting the number of replies

Tags: marketing-cloud, analytics, custom-reports

Is there a way how to count the number of replies to emails in MC? Cannot find any report for that.

Thank you.

Comment: I agree with @iManage - this would need to be something you talk with your account manager on.  Once you hear back, please update your question with what the solution was to help anyone else that is having this issue.

Answer (score 1):

There's no report that I'm aware of, and no publicly accessible data view.

A custom report would be possible - reach out to your account manager for further scope and costs